# Android Studio 3.6.1-4.0 code formatting, keep lines without breaks while having annotations

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, formatting

I'm using android studio 3.6.1 and I'm trying to keep fields with annotations connected without line breaks between them after code reformat (Command+Option+L). In older versions of android studio I have no problem to do it. I tried to change **Code Style** configuration but didn't manage to make it work. any idea?

what I want to achieve:

[image: what i want]

this is what i get after code reformat:

[image: what i get]

thanks